# Distributing iPhone App to developers in your team through iTunes

Tags: iphone

Was wondering if you can distribute your App to other developers in your team through iTunes. I guess you would upload the App as a beta version through iTunes Connect and anyone with a provisioned iPhone would receive the update. I didn't think it was possible but someone told me they were sure you could.

If this is not possible are there any other benefits of a company standard enrollment besides being able to add other people so they can get the same resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your other team members don't have access to Xcode then you can do this through ad-hoc distribution.

First you need to get the device ID's (GUID) for all the involved members and generate a provisioning profile containing the ID's.

Then once you have built your executable application just zip this together with the provisioning profile.

The team members can install the application (including the provisioning profile) by dropping the application into iTunes and syncing with the iPhone.

Comment: Thanks, shortly after I asked the question someone showed me this exact method. Not what the manager originally thought was possible but this is the closest thing possible.

Answer (score 1):

If the developers are in your team, meaning the team as defined on the developer portal, far better for them to sync to the source (i.e. latest or specific label) you want to test and to build and install it themselves since they cal all have their own provisioning profiles. It would be possible for one developer to have all devices on one provisioning profile and to do all the build and install tasks for everyone, or it would be possible to use the ad-hoc distribution, but you need to sign up and pay for that method of course. I do not think there are any other ways to do this.

Comment: By source are you referring to something like subversion?

Comment: Right - I hope you are using some kind of source control. There are plenty of good free ones to choose from, like SVN, git, mercurial etc.

Comment: Yeah we are. The person who thought you could share it through iTunes was a manager, not a programmer so wasn't really in authority to know. Not technical either so don't really want to set up Xcode and subversion so he can compile and install it himself either.

Comment: In my experience when managers are involved some programmer gets handed a phone and asked to do the update. Works OK.